# Reduce a function on the sphere of radius R to a function on the unit sphere

Tags: special-functions, spherical-harmonics

Suppose that $\psi(\theta,\phi)$ is a function on the sphere of radius R.

Can we say $\psi(R\theta,R\phi)$ is a function on the sphere of radius $1$ ?

Comment: No. Presumably $\theta$ and $\phi$ are angles, and $\psi$ is a function that wants a pair of angles as its input. But $R\theta$ and $R\phi$ are not angles, they are arc-lengths. I would think that $\psi(\theta,\phi)$ would describe a function on no matter what sphere of positive radius.

Comment: @Lubin So we can write $\psi(\theta,\phi)$ as a linear combination of spherical harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$ ?

Comment: Well, I thought (and still think) that $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the (angular) variables (inputs) to the function $\psi$. Accordingly, the answer to your question would be that the corresponding function on the sphere of radius $1$ is $\psi(\theta,\phi)$. What this might have to do with spherical harmonics I have no notion of.